# Docker container running supervisor shuts down too early

Tags: mysql, docker, supervisord

I am running a docker container with multiple processes (to achieve a LAMP environment) by using supervisor as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/). Everything works fine but when I stop the container the MySQL process doesn't get properly terminated even though I've set up supervisor's pidproxy in the supervisor config

```
[program:mysql]
command=/usr/bin/pidproxy /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid /bin/sh -c "exec /usr/bin/mysqld_safe"
```

When I access the container through nsenter and restart the MySQL daemon with

```
supervisorctl restart mysql
```

the shutdown completes without throwing an error next time it comes up. So I think supervisor is configured correctly. To me it seems docker (I am running 1.2.0) terminates the container just a bit early while mysqld is still shutting down.

### Edit

I was able to debug some more details by running `supervisord` with the `-e debug` switch.

Shutdown with `supervisorctl restart mysql` via nsenter:

```
DEBG fd 17 closed, stopped monitoring <POutputDispatcher at 39322256 for <Subprocess at 38373280 with name mysql in state RUNNING> (stderr)>
DEBG fd 14 closed, stopped monitoring <POutputDispatcher at 39324128 for <Subprocess at 38373280 with name mysql in state RUNNING> (stdout)>
DEBG killing mysql (pid 1128) with signal SIGTERM
INFO stopped: mysql (exit status 0)
DEBG received SIGCLD indicating a child quit
CRIT reaped unknown pid 1129)
DEBG received SIGCLD indicating a child quit
```

And externally via `docker restart container_name`:

```
DEBG fd 17 closed, stopped monitoring <POutputDispatcher at 39290136 for <Subprocess at 38373280 with name mysql in state RUNNING> (stderr)>
DEBG fd 14 closed, stopped monitoring <POutputDispatcher at 39290424 for <Subprocess at 38373280 with name mysql in state RUNNING> (stdout)>
DEBG killing mysql (pid 7871) with signal SIGTERM
INFO stopped: mysql (exit status 0)
DEBG received SIGCLD indicating a child quit
```

This is the process structure before the first attempt:

```
 1128 S      0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/pidproxy /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
 1129 S      0:00  \_ /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
 1463 Sl     0:00      \_ /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-erro
```

So while `pid 1463` gets properly reaped as it's in `/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`, `pid 1129` causes the trouble as docker shuts down the container before it's gone. Is it a bug in supervisor's pidproxy or can it be fixed by a different configuration?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and I fixed it by not using mysql_safe, but rather starting mysql directly. I did this by seeing what command mysql_safe generated in the `ps aux` overview.

Maybe it fails because `mysql_safe` doesn't create a proper parent -> child process relationship?

Anyway my config would look something like this if I use your mysql process as a template:

```
[program:mysql]
command=/usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-erro
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Docker will only wait for ten seconds before killing a container it's trying to stop (or restart).  This is so that the action requested is ultimately carried out, and it doesn't just hang.  You can configure the time period using the "--time" parameter on "docker stop" or "docker restart".

Comment: Thanks for the idea Arthur, but the proper restart inside the container just takes about one second in my case. So adding the `--time` parameter has no effect. Supervisor really seems to exit with 0 before the intermediate mysqld_safe process terminates.